# Pygame not responding when trying to show texts on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pygame

I've installed pygame version 1.9.4 on python 3.5.3 using instructions on [programarcadegames.com](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=foreword&lang=en). When I use pygame to draw lines and shapes it's just fine but when I try to use `pygame.font.SysFont` the pygame is not responding anymore. For example when I run following code a non-responsive pygame window will show up:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

size = (400, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
            done = True  # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25, True, False)

    text = font.render("Some Text", True, BLACK)
    screen.blit(text, [0, 0])

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: just try with `font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25, True, False)`, maybe it didn't find Calibri

Comment: @PRMoureu Thank you but that's not working.

Comment: How do you run this program? --- Probably not related to the problem, but better define the font above the while loop (this line: `font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25, True, False)`).

Comment: @skrx I'm trying to learn pygame using the [programarcadegames](http://programarcadegames.com) and this snippet structure is based on this site!

Comment: Do you start the game in IDLE? IDLE has sometimes trouble with pygame programs especially if fonts are involved. You could try to run the program from the terminal.

Comment: @srkx No, I run it using terminal!

Comment: The code you've posted should work correctly and I can't reproduce the error (in Windows (maybe it's a osx related problem)). BTW, what exactly do you mean with "non-responsive pygame window"? Is it not possible to close the window or to drag it around? Try to replace `pygame.font.SysFont` with `pygame.font.Font(None, 25)`.

Comment: @skrx non responsive means that a grey window will open and nothing can be done with that window and no event is processed in the code and nothing is drawn. Replacing worked for me. Thanks a lot. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing `font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25, True, False)` with `font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)` fixed the problem, but it is still unclear what caused it.